# How to update snippet and status values of already uploaded video through YouTube API v3?

Tags: ajax, http, youtube, youtube-api, metadata

How to change the snippet and status values of an already uploaded video through YouTube API v3 "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos" using AJAX request?

**My UPDATED CODE (NOT Working):**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        dataType: "jsonp", 
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id,snippet,status&key=<API Key>",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + <Access Token>
        },
        data: $.parseJSON('{"id": "<Video ID>", "snippet": {"title": "New Title", "description": "New Description"}, "status": {"privacyStatus": "unlisted"}}'), 
        success: function(data, error, completeError) {
            alert( JSON.stringify(data));
            alert( JSON.stringify(error));
            alert( JSON.stringify(completeError));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a PUT request to the [`videos/update`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update) endpoint with the parameter `part=id,snippet,status`:

```
HTTP PUT: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id,snippet,status&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Body of your request:

```
{
    "id": "VIDEO_ID",
    "snippet": { // any snippet fields you want to change
        "description": "New Video Description"
    },
    "status": { // any status fields you want to change
        "privacyStatus": "public"
    }
}
```

Comment: the url should be as follows (coorect me if i'm wrong)

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/update?part=id,snippet,status&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Comment: @user2985035 It's not `/videos/update`, it's just `/videos`.  The full URL in my answer is where you should call the PUT request: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id%2C+snippet&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Comment: Ok, but I'm confused with this "part=id%2C+snippet"  segment in the url

Comment: @user2985035 oh I see what you're saying.  I think that was an issue with the URL encoding on Google's side.  The full url should look something like this: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id,snippet,status&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

You need to pass in `id` to get the video, and `snippet` and `status` because you are modifying those properties.

Comment: @user2985035 `%2C` is the URL encoding escape character for `,`.  You will have to encode the URL parameters before making the request, so that looks right.

Comment: Ok, that's fine. Should I pass the Json objects as they are or I should stringify them as JSON.stringify(data) ?

Comment: @user2985035 If you're creating the JSON as a dictionary, there should be no need to encode it.  If you're constructing it as a string, use `parseJSON`.  It might look something like this: `$.parseJSON('{"id": "VIDEO_ID", "snippet": {"title": "New Title", "description": "New Description"}, "status": {"privacyStatus": "unlisted"}}')`

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately its not updating the video values its giving back the exact same values without any change and without errors too

Comment: @user2985035 Are you sure you're setting up the HTTP post request properly?  Can you post your full code in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used when having a play around. It works well though. 
It doesn't use JQuery but should point you in the right direction.

```
function UpdateVideoInfo(video_id){
        var resource = {
                'snippet':{
                    'title' : 'test title',
                    'description' : 'test description',
                    'categoryId' : 22
                },
                'status' : {
                    'privacyStatus' : 'private'
                },
                'id': video_id
            };

        post_string = JSON.stringify(resource);

        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open('PUT', 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,status', true);
        ajax.setRequestHeader("Authorization", '<?php echo $authorization_header; ?>');
        ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        ajax.send(post_string);

        ajax.onload = function() {
            if (ajax.status == 200) {
                alert(ajax.responseText);
            }
        };
    }
```